# .NET Membership and Cookies?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

**Hi,**

I need to determind how my site uses Cookies to inform the user in proper way.

The solutio is a ASP.NET MVC website using .NET Membership. Im storing data in sessions on server but nothing is saved manual to cookies on the client. I Supose however that the ASP.NET Membership is using cookies (for autologin) but im not sure witch data it really stores on the client?

Could you pleas explain or give me a link for this?

**BestRegards**

Comment: the Membership does store an authentication token in a cookie.

Comment: Okay is that all? and how does it look like? Is it only when using autologin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forms authentication ticket (the cookie on the client) stores values such as the username and cookie expiration time along with some other boolean fields related to the remember me checkbox and sliding expiration.  This is if you use cookie-based forms authentication which is the default and a typical choice.  More information can be found at the following site:

[Forms Authentication Explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

It is important to note that sessions and the forms authentication ticket (cookie) are not related in any way.  You can have a session without being logged in and you can login and never touch the session object.  This is an important difference.

**EDIT**

This cookie is not used for 'auto login'.  After *authentication*, putting in a username and password, the cookie is created and is used for *authorization* - can you access these resources - throughout your site.

Comment: Thanks, how does auto login work if it is not using cookies? And how long will the cookie for the membership exist on the client?

Comment: I actually do not know what you mean by 'autologin' exactly.  If you are asking what I think you are, that is controlled by the browser.  The auth cookie does not store the password, therefore it cannot autolog you in.  As for the cookie itself, I am not sure if the browser cleans up expired cookies automatically or not, that would be an implementation question based upon the browser I would think.

Comment: @SnowJim - Depending on what you mean by "auto-login" if you set the `Forms Authentication` cookie to be **persistent**, and `SignOut` is not invoked, and the browser is **not** set to clear cookies on exit/close, you *can* have "auto-login".

Comment: @SnowJim - if you want to inspect cookies, just use Chrome/FF/Safari/IE web developer tools and inspect the Request/Response in Network tab. You will see cookies being set by server in Response and sent (by your browser) in Request.

Comment: @EdSF - that's correct that you would never be logged out, but you are not really being auto-loggedin either.  Not trying to be picky or whatever, but I don't think SnowJim should think that the user is being reauthenticated to the server, just has a still valid cookie.  And I realize that is why you put it in quotes :)

Comment: Thanks! I have built a manual autlogin berfore with ASP.NET where I generated a GUID that would make a autologin next time. I thought that the Membership worked in the same way but I supose not.

Comment: Im however still not totaly clear on what the Membership will store in the cookie when using form authentication? Why would it need a cookie at all if it was not to hold information from session to session? On your explaination it sounds more like it keeps data between calls in one specific session? For me a session is created the first time the client connects to the service and then this session will be keept to the end (timout or signout).

Comment: @SnowJim The Forms Authentication (FA) ticket and Session are mutually exclusive and have nothing to do with each other.  You can use session without signing into a site.  The FA ticket stores the username and expiration time.  This allows the application to validate that you are the same user between request as well as use the username to authorize the user to the content on the site.  As to why use the cookie over session to store this information, this is another question/debate entirely (security, persistence, etc)

Comment: @SnowJim - as Tommy explained, `session cookies` and forms auth cookies, while both being cookies, are **not** related - they are different cookies. If you use the web developer tools mentioned above, you'll see 2 cookies. HTTP is stateless. Cookies are how your client/browser tells the server, "its me".

Comment: Thanks! So the cookie for the membership is used between request(so calde session cookie). The autologin do not create any cookies and is handled by the browser in another way. When declearing for the enduser about the cookie usage of the site I only have to say session cookies that keep track of the user between requests?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Membership enabled sites will have up to 3 cookies:

1. Session token
2. Authentication token
3. Roles cache (if enabled in
   web.config)

To see them, open your site in the browser of your choice, login, and inspect the cookies. In IE its Tools -> Internet Options -> Settings (next to Browsing History) -> View Files